# how to run my php file from command line

Tags: php, windows, command-line

I would like my code to run in the command line (cmd) and then output the result to a text file. The text file should then contain 'hello world'.

I tried

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\hello.php"
```

Comment: if you add `>answer.txt` it should work

Answer (score 3):

The answer is rather simple,

add `> answer.txt` to the command and it will be saved in answer.txt

so it will be

```
cd "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13"
php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\hello.php" > answer.txt
```

the `>` says that all the output must be redirected

for more information see

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx

**EDIT**

If you also want to provide input you can do

```
cd "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13"
php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\hello.php" < input.ini > answer.txt
```

Comment: what if i want the result of the script open a window with the result in the txt. I have a script that runs ip addresses but i would like the results to be outputted example:C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13>php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\hello.php" input:test.ini output:results.txt